# How can I remove the status bar in Android Studio activity preview

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I find the "Preview" view in Android Studio super useful to see how my UI will appear on the device. The preview *almost* matches my in-app layout.

Our app has a fullscreen UI, which even hides the status bar. This works great on the device, but the preview insists on displaying the status bar. I haven't been able to figure out how to remove it editing an activity ui.

To be clear, I'm not talking about the App Titlebar, or the system buttons (home, back, etc).

[image: the android status bar in preview]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your layout theme to NoTitleBar.FullScreen.

[image: 1.]

[image: 2.]

Comment: FRICKIN HERO. Will accept your answer when the cooldown runs down.

Answer (score 1):

With Android studio version 3.3.2:

[image: How to Enable/Disable status bar in android studio app preview]

Answer (score -2):

In Previews screen, Apply NoTitleBar.FullScreen theme to your layout.