# How do I hide the navigation bar in the editor for android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-navigation-bar

How do I make the bottom navigation bar disappear in the visual XML editor in Android Studio? I already have the AppTheme set to NoActionBar. The navigation bar is very annoying because my phone does not have one so when I place something on the very bottom of my app in the visual editor (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxP84.png), This happens when I run the app on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXxsw.jpg . Someone please help me. I cannot continue my development until this issue is fixed.

I have looked at both of these and they were no help to me. 
[How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)
[How to emulate immersive mode in layout editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291890/how-to-emulate-immersive-mode-in-layout-editor)

Here is the screenshot of the Navigation bar which I want removed: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QRRx.jpg

Here is my XML Code for activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#474747"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/typeMessage"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="504dp"
        android:background="#595858"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="#969494"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="504dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/typeMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageOutput"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:background="#595858"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/typeMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my code for MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291890/how-to-emulate-immersive-mode-in-layout-editor

Comment: these two links didnt help.

Answer (score 3):

It may be too late, but in case you haven't figured it out yet, I think I may have found a solution for you:

Put this in your onCreate()

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Then add this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (hasFocus) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
}
```

Here's the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation

Comment: Man you are a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @EthanAdams - I'd appreciate it if you'd mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!